# Was the Cubs World Series celebration the 7th largest gathering in human history?

Tags: history

[This news page](http://www.fox32chicago.com/news/local/215601786-story) claims that the Cubs World Series celebration ranks as 7th largest gathering in human history.  Is this statement true?  [Wikipedia has a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_peaceful_gatherings_in_history) that would place it as 18th.

There are many other lists of largest gatherings on the web.  So it is possible that both of these lists are wrong.

Comment: Seems you answered it already ... so what is there to answer?

Comment: Which source if any is right?

Comment: Wikipedia sources their claims ... so it seems the Chicago Cubs claim (which is on that Wikipedia page in the correct place, btw) from the local new affiliate is wrong